# Unable to create a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a script for log parsing.
I got a file in which logs are jumbled up. Every first line of a particular log will have time stamp so I want to sort them using that.

For e.g.

10:48  Start
.
.
10:50 start
.
.
10:42 start
First line will contain key word ‘Start’ and the time stamp. The lines between ‘Start’ and before next ‘start’ are one set. I want to sort all of these sets in log files based on their time stamp.

Code Logic:
I thought of creating dictionary, where I will pick this time and assign it as ‘key’ and the text in value for that log set. And then I will sort the ‘keys’ in dictionary and print their ‘values’ in that sorted order in a file.
However I am getting error “TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'”

```
write1 = False
x = 0
search3 = "start"
matched = dict()
matched = {}

# fo is a list which is defined elsewhre in the code.

for line in fo:

    if search3 in line:

    #got the Hello2 printed which indicates script enters this loop

        print('hello2')
        write1 = True
        x +=1
        time = line.split()[3]
        name1 = [time.split(':')[0] +":"+time.split(':')[1] + ":"+     time.split(':')[2]]
        matched[name1] = line

    elif write1:
        matched[name1] += line

print(matched.keys())
```

Please let me know if my logic and the way I am doing is correct?

Comment: dict key should not be an list. "name1" is list here. Make it as string or tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `name1` as a list. Lists aren't hashable, only tuples are. However, I assume that you want name1 to be a string so you just want to remove the brackets:

```
name1 = time.split(':')[0] +":"+time.split(':')[1] + ":"+     time.split(':')[2]
```